# EditText in Spanish

Tags: android, localization, translation

I have the following EditText:

```
EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSp);
```

When user types in this EditText, it should display text in Spanish instead of English.
How can I achieve this?

**Note:** My application's language is English.

Comment: So a user will type in English and the text will be automatically translated to Spanish?

Comment: Yes. For that, should I need run-time translator? or that can be done by just adding Spanish font .ttf file as Typeface?

Comment: Yes, you need a translation service. In most cases, Spanish words can already be presented using the same fonts as English words, so "adding Spanish font .ttf file" isn't a solution. Changing the font won't cause the words and phrases to translate themselves into another language.

Comment: Alright, Thanks. Then How can I set the application language (Locale) ?

Comment: What @user113215 is suggesting is that you grab the text from the input using a listener.  Send that text to a library that you have within your app, that will translate the text to Spanish if possible.  Then set the input value to the translated Spanish text.  You just need to find a translation library to add to your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the locale at runtime using that code:

```
 Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();

 Locale locale = new Locale("en"); //<--- use your locale code here
 Locale.setDefault(locale);

 Configuration config = new Configuration();
 config.locale = locale;

 res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
```

I assume you need to reset your layout afterwards too.

Comment: this would change the locale for the entire system, correct?  Meaning if the user closes the app or goes to another app, Spanish would be displayed?

Comment: no it will change the local for your current activity. So it wont affect your system as far as I know.

Comment: It is not working for my application. It changes nothing when I use "es" as locale. Everything is in English.

Comment: @Shani [Locales](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) are used to alter the presentation of information such as numbers or dates to suit the conventions in the region they describe. Its use is to change the decimal point/digit grouping characters (e.g., 1,000.24 vs 1.000,24) or date formats, not to translate your UI.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post, it is not possible to change the locale for a currently running app.

[Google Groups -> Android Developers](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/VEAWMCdyIWg/W71DOADxsqAJ)

The "DH" that Richard mentions in this post is an Android Framework Engineer.  Look at Richard's previous post for a link to her comments.

Comment: So, as a developer, one can only use English in app?

Comment: One can only use the locale language for input.

Comment: you could have some "overlay" telling the user to change keyboard language.  On the Samsung keyboard I know you can swipe the keyboard to change language input.  Not an answer that will work for all keyboards though :(